# Setting iptables rule for all protocols for specific source and destination ports

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

Is it possible to add a IPTABLES rule which allows all the protocols for specific source and destination ports? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 172.27.0.254/255.255.255.255 -d 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 -p 0 --sport 0:65535 --dport 1191:1191 -j ACCEPT

iptables error: unknown option `--sport`
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many protocols do not have ports (gre, icmp, etc).

Comment: Yes. I notice when you use -p tcp --dports and save the firewall state, the save file also has -m tcp on each line, which implies to me that you cant do it for multiple protocols. I don't know for certain though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `--sport` or `--dport` with `-p 0` (or `-p all`) because IP transport layer can have protocols that aren't tied to ports. You can do this with protocols like udp/tcp/sctp/etc.